# Embedding jetty server into android applications

Tags: java, android, jetty, war, embedded-jetty

So far i am trying making sample android applications to embedded android jetty web server enables to run samples hello-3.1.war from Google code. While i run hello-3.1 in eclipse then null pointer exception has been occur.

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /hello-3.1/sayit. Reason:

    INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

Caused by:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mortbay.ijetty.hello.HelloWorld.init(HelloWorld.java:29)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Powered by Jetty://
```

Hello-3.1 web application Codings:

### Web.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    version="3.0"> 
 <!--  <servlet id="jsp">
     <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>logVerbosityLevel</param-name>
         <param-value>DEBUG</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>fork</param-name>
         <param-value>false</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
         <param-value>false</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet> -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.mortbay.ijetty.hello.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/sayit/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

### Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.ijetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-webapps-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
  <name>I-Jetty :: Hello</name>
  <version>3.1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
          <verbose>false</verbose>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

          <!-- Convert the compiled classes into a clases.dex. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-dex</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <!-- executable>${env.ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools/dx</executable -->
              <executable>java</executable>
              <arguments>
               <!-- <argument>-JXmx1024M</argument> -->
                <argument>-jar</argument>
                <argument>${env.ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools/lib/dx.jar</argument>
                <argument>--dex</argument>
                <argument>--verbose</argument>
                <argument>--core-library</argument>
                <argument>--output=${project.build.directory}/classes.dex</argument>
                <argument>--positions=lines</argument>
                <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes/</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copydex</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <mkdir
                  dir="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF/lib" />
                <jar
                  basedir="${project.build.directory}"
                  update="true"
                  includes="classes.dex"
                  destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF/lib/classes.zip" />
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api-2.5</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>


      <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
 <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-jsp-2.1</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.2.v20101205</version>
    </dependency> -->
   <!--  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-2.1-glassfish</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.v20100127</version>
    </dependency>-->
  <!--   <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency> -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp_api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android</artifactId>
      <version>${android.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

JSP is not possible on Android.

Or to be more accurate, compiling JSP on an Android device is not possible.

What you need to do:

1. Remove the JspServlet from your web.xml or webdefault.xml.  You can't use it on Android anyway.
2. Pre-compile your JSP's on your development machine and include the compiled JSP references in your web.xml.  Look at the various JSPC tooling out there, they all support this.
3. Dexify the post-compiled WAR file using the techniques outlined at the i-jetty project.

This will allow you to develop with JSPs, and use them on Android, but not as the raw `*.jsp` file itself, but rather the compiled `*.class` files (which are then dexified into the Android bytecode format).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am new on developing web oriented programming. So i trouble to understand your explanation.Yet i try to run sample web application that was posted by google code to support android which is run by jetty.yet, I don't know where i am mistake.Now i am sending some update codings and exceptions.Kindly to see, and pls share where i am mistake. Better to send sample web applications codings(war,android source to run war file) runs by android with jetty.

Comment: I am waiting for good reply from u. Please help me out of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look over NanoHTTPDserver, it's a light web-server which runs in Android, you'll have to do a lot of handling yourself but it may just server your purposes.

[NanoHTTPD gist link](https://gist.github.com/komamitsu/1893396)